# Who wins the game of "Sticky Gomoku" on an infinite board?

Tags: game, board-games

This is a [Gomoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomoku) like game, played by two players with Go pieces (black and white stones) on an infinite (in all four directions) Go board.

Rules

1. **Four in a row:** players alternate turns placing a stone of their color on an empty intersection. Black plays first. The winner is the first player to form an unbroken chain of four stones horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.
2. **Sticky:** except for black's first stone, every stone must be placed adjacent to one of your opponent's.

Question: can black force a win?

Comment: Does "adjacent" include diagonally adjacent?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Sure. Every intersection has eight adjacent neighbors.

Comment: This is actually much tricker than I thought. Getting 3-in-a-row is rarely an immediate threat because the blank space is usually not adjacent to the opponent and so not immediately playable.

Comment: The only possible endgame I think is to create two 3-in-a-rows with one move, where the move itself and the two fourths are pairwise adjacent (forming a small triangle). Obviously the problem is how to force such a position in the first place...

Comment: Looks like a funny game to play with family or friends, but I suspect that a systematic study would simply be an exhaustive search, probably computer-aided. Maybe @Eric can clarify whether there is a clever approach to be expected.

Comment: @WhatsUp I heard of this game from an internet friend, who allegedly had invented it a few years ago, and had played it with friends since. The conjecture is that optimal play for both players will end in a draw, but no one is sure.

Comment: @Eric I see, thanks for the clarification! I guess it would be very hard to solve, as one doesn't expect to find a finite game tree that totally describes optimal moves.